# Gap between Logo Header and Menu

Tags: html, css

Tried to create a new header with responsive logo and menu. Every thing look working fine now after few consultation and advised from stackoverflow expert.

I am having problems with the gap between header and navbar as attached in image.

Have work around with margin-bottom, vertical-align and position but are not working.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav");

  console.log(barIcon)
  if (x.className === "navbar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
    var barIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-bars')[0];
    barIcon.classList.add("fa-times");
    barIcon.classList.remove("fa-bars");
  } else {
    var closeIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-times')[0];
    closeIcon.classList.remove("fa-times");
    closeIcon.classList.add("fa-bars");
    x.className = "navbar";
  }
}
```

```css
#logo {
  background: transparent url("images/airlineshq-logo.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  width: 1040px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #logo {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 18px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #0033CC;
  color: white;
}

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}

.navbar a:hover,
input:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  color: black;
}


/* CSS for search box */

.navbar .search-box {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .search-box input {
  padding: 12px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar .search-box button {
  color: #999;
  border: navajowhite;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a,
  .navbar .search-box,
  .navbar .search-icon {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .search-box {
    float: none;
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 4%;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .search-icon {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <header id="logo"></header>
  <div class="navbar" id="nav">
    <a href="https://klia2.co" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="../facilities/index.htm">Facilities</a>
    <a href="../airlines/index.htm">Airlines Offices</a>
    <form class="search-box">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
      <button type="submit" class="search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Kindly share your HTML code along with the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the snippet, I see no gap between the `<header>` and the `<div class="navbar">`.

The header styles in `#logo` have a set `height: 160px;` which gives the illusion of a gap, but all it is doing, is what it has been asked to do (have a height of 160px).